# Android & React Native: emulator won't send out http request after https enabled

Tags: android, react-native

After enabled `https` on back end nodejs server, the http request URL was changed from `http` to `https` in React Native 0.66 app. Now in Android emulator (API 27), the app does not send out any http request to back end server at all. `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` was added to `AndroidManifest.xml` but it didn't help (removing it has no impact either). It must be the issue about late android API which requires `https` in production. But I don't quite understand why `https` didn't work in Android emulator.

The development platform is macOS Big Sur for both IOS and Android which open their own emulators respectively. The IOS version of the app works fine after `https` was enabled. But android version of the app does not.